# Events for the border of a form?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, winapi, user-interface

I want to know when the user has the mouse over the border of a form. I also want to be able to know if its the top/bottom or left/right border.
There does not seem to be any events for this. I have tried using MouseMove on the form but it only fires when it is "inside" the form.

I have tried looking at the Bounds property but that does not have any events.
What can I do to solve this?

Comment: I don't think there are WinForms events for the non-client area beyond the caption buttons. You may have to play with what's called window messages but I'm not sure which are raised for the window frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the WNDPROC method and look for WM_NC* messages.

This link should get you started: [Mouse events from a non-client area of a control](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/cf851eb4-52ec-4519-8d1c-eb52bc32eafd)